# Recipes for HTML/CSS

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create this 3-columns fluid layout?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/how-to-create-this-3-columns-fluid-layout)

I'm new to HTML/CSS and I'm having a hell of a time getting things to lay out like I'd expect them to!  It would be really helpful if there was a gallery of *very* simple HTML example that covered a lot of common cases.  For instance:

- How do I get a liquid main area with a fixed sidebar on the right, (or left, or both sides)?
- How do I keep my footer from sliding under the main area when the screen is too wide?
- Etc.

Surely several such websites exist, but I'm having trouble finding one that's really helpful to me right now.  Do you have any recommendations?

*Note, I'm new on this site, so if this question belongs on a different Stack Exchange website, then please direct me there.*

Comment: Yes, Stack Overflow is the right place for coding stuff http://stackoverflow.com/ And I believe that if you search for this there, you would find answers.

Comment: Not really individual sites, but google can usually answer you for that. For instance, google "two column liquid layout with fixed sidebar".

Comment: Oh, and this question would be applicable to StackOverflow as well.

Comment: As for tools, you might want to search for CSS frameworks, see: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/which-css-grid-framework-should-you-use-for-web-design/

Comment: It isn't answer for your question, but it might become invaluable if you want to dig deeper into the subject: http://www.quirksmode.org/.

Comment: While not exactly the same, this is close enough to [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/how-to-create-this-3-columns-fluid-layout) so I'm closing as duplicate...

Answer (score 3):

I'd check out Matthew James Taylor's site. He has posted some great liquid layout tutorials and other things, including some templates that you can download:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts

Answer (score 1):

There are gobs and gobs of sites like this. Sitpoint.com rounded up 450+ examples. http://designfestival.com/450-css-layouts/

To answer your question, I think this layout will serve you well http://www.intensivstation.ch/files/en_templates/temp07.html